# How-To Perl recursive regex

Tags: regex, perl, testing, functional-testing, prompt

I have outputs from a device I need to test and mostly the response is one line, but sometimes it is two lines. Which I handle with a simple regex parsing one or two lines

```
if ($prompt =~ /(\s.*?)\r\n(.*)/)
{
   Note('Multiline '.$string);
   TestPrompt($string, $1);
   TestPrompt($string, $2);
}
else
{
   TestPrompt($string, $prompt);
}
```

But what if the response is more than two lines? This code cannot handle the additional lines and I'd like to be robust in my design. Is there a way to capture from regex for use in a `foreach`?

Comment: You should provide some input and some desired output. Not possible to help you without those two :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use the `split` function instead to do this? Here is a [link to some examples](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/perlfunc/split_function.html) of usage. For your example, why not do this:

```
my @lines=split /\r\n/,$prompt;

Note("Multiline $string") if @lines>1; 

foreach my $line (@lines) 
{ 
   TestPrompt($string, $line);
}
```

Comment: +1  I'd suggest `@lines > 1` rather than your `$#lines` check.

Comment: @pilcrow, done... Also replaced the '.' concatenation of the parameter to Note with a double-quoted string literal for better readability.

Comment: Looks just like what I needed, now I need to figure out why I couldn't think of `split` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could split at newlines:

```
my @lines = split /\r\n/, $prompt;
foreach (@lines) {
    TestPrompt( $string, $_ );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global match in list context:

```
    my @prompts = m{(\s*\S*?)\r\n}g;
    for my $prompt (@prompts) {
        print "$prompt\n";
    }
```